# Excel fill rows with data from columns in separate sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with lots of sheets named "xxA" and "xxB" with xx being consecutive numbers.

Each sheet has the following format:

```
header1      header2      header3      header 4     header5
ingredient1  description  xx           20           g
ingredient2  description  xx           34           ml
ingredient3  description  xx           56           g
```

and some other rows at the end. 
Basically I want to create a new sheet in which rows 2-27 from column D are copied to a column named "value" and create two new columns with the number in the sheet name and another one with the letter like so:

```
subject    condition    ingredient    value
21         A            ingredient1   20
21         A            ingredient2   34
21         A            ingredient3   56
21         B            ingredient1   34
21         B            ingredient2   23
21         B            ingredient3   47
...
```

I tried messing with pivot tables but that doesn't really work. I don't know how to create a VBA, so any direction on that would be great if that is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. It copies data from worksheets and gets the sheet names split as asked. I have it hard coded to only work for double digit numbers and single letters. Do you have sheets that do not fit that form? If so, I can rework my code!

ORIGINAL:

```
Sub SheetSummary()

'Make new worksheet with required headers
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.name = "Summary"
range("A1").Value = "subject"
range("B1").Value = "condition"
range("C1").Value = "ingredient"
range("D1").Value = "value"

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsNum As String
Dim wsLetter As String
Dim wsLastRow As Long
Dim sumLastRow As Long
Dim myCell As range
Dim nextOpenRow As Long

'If a worksheet is not the summary, then get the data
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.name <> "Summary" Then
        wsNum = Left(ws.name, 2)
        wsLetter = Right(ws.name, 1)

        wsLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        nextOpenRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ws.range("A2", ws.Cells(wsLastRow, "A")).Copy

        range("C" & nextOpenRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        ws.range("C2", ws.Cells(wsLastRow, "C")).Copy

        range("D" & nextOpenRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        For Each myCell In range("A2", Cells(lastRow, "A"))
            If myCell.Value = "" Then
                myCell.Value = wsNum
            End If
        Next myCell

        For Each myCell In range("B2", Cells(lastRow, "B"))
            If myCell.Value = "" Then
                myCell.Value = wsLetter
            End If
        Next myCell
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

EDIT:

```
Sub SheetSummary()

'Make new worksheet with required headers
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.name = "Summary"
range("A1").Value = "subject"
range("B1").Value = "condition"
range("C1").Value = "ingredient"
range("D1").Value = "value"

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsNum As String
Dim wsLetter As String
Dim wsLastRow As Long
Dim sumLastRow As Long
Dim myCell As range
Dim nextOpenRow As Long

'If a worksheet is not the summary, then get the data
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.name <> "Summary" Then
        wsNum = Left(ws.name, 2)
        wsLetter = Right(ws.name, 1)

        wsLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        nextOpenRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ws.range("A2:A27").Copy

        range("C" & nextOpenRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        ws.range("D2:D27").Copy

        range("D" & nextOpenRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        For Each myCell In range("A2", Cells(lastRow, "A"))
            If myCell.Value = "" Then
                myCell.Value = wsNum
            End If
        Next myCell

        For Each myCell In range("B2", Cells(lastRow, "B"))
            If myCell.Value = "" Then
                myCell.Value = wsLetter
            End If
        Next myCell
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this is going on the right direction, but I misguided you with my incorrect table structure.. there is an additional useless column. So your code is not reading in the correct column with the values (that is column D in every sheet from rows 2 to 27 -- 28 and 29 have some junk and fomulas). Otherwise it correctly created the subject and condition columns. All sheets are named with double digits and a single letter so your code is spot on there.

Comment: @Santiago Sorry I misunderstood. I added a modified code below my original one. It is very similar, but I think it will work if I am understanding what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know VBA I wouldn't recommend taking that route. You can acheive everything you want using Excel formulas.

To get the name of a sheet use:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

Replace "A1" with a reference to the cell on the worksheet you want the name of.

Then use the `Left()` function to split out the "xx" from the name and then use the `Right()` function to split out "A"

Hope this helps.